# Why factor matters in stripplot (lattice)?

Tags: r, lattice

I'm trying to learn lattice, and I've come to this example:

```
stripplot(depth ~ factor(mag), data = quakes)
```

Results in this:

[image: factored lattice]

Whereas this one:

```
stripplot(depth ~ mag, data = quakes)
```

Results in this:

[image: unfactored lattice]

What's the difference? Why does it matter? What's happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this seems to be a quirk in how formulas are interpreted in `bwplot`. All `stripplot` does is call `bwplot` with a different panel function. This means that

```
stripplot(depth ~ mag, data = quakes)
```

is equivalent to

```
bwplot(depth ~ mag, data = quakes, panel=panel.stripplot)
```

(assuming you haven't messed with the "prepanel.default.stripplot" option). So basically a `stripplot` is just like a box-and-whisker plot but instead of drawing the boxes, it draws each observations as a point and adds some jitter so they all don't fall on top of each other. Observe these 4 plots (here i use `bwplot` so it's easier to see the direction/orientation of the data)

```
bwplot(depth ~ mag, data = quakes, main="bw d~m")
bwplot(mag ~ depth, data = quakes, main="bw m~d")
bwplot(depth ~ factor(mag), data = quakes, main="bw d~f(m)")
bwplot(factor(depth) ~ mag, data = quakes, main="bw f(d)~m")
```

[image]

When drawing a bwplot/scatterplot, one of your variables should be a factor. That's how you get the discrete groups. If you do not specify a factor, by default `bwplot` will turn the response variable from your formula into a factor. However, if the response is continuous and `x` is a factor, `bwplot` assumes you want `x` to be the discrete variable instead of `y` so it switches from the default horizontal to the a vertical orientation.

So when both are numeric (as in the case `stripplot(depth ~ mag, data = quakes)`) the `depth` is converted to factor which is undesirable. But when you specify a factor as the `x` and have a numeric `y` (as in `stripplot(depth ~ factor(mag), data = quakes)`), `bwplot` changes it usual layout from vertical to horizontal to accommodate.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Ok, so basically if none is a factor it coerces the first variable in the formula to be a factor, resulting in this undesirable effect. The stripplot seemed to me like a variation on the xyplot, not on the barplot. I guess that's why I missed it.